# How can I access my Kubernetes cluster application from outside the VM it's deployed on?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have an application running in three pods I want to reach the application through the internet, I tried to use ingress and nodeport by trying to access to the <publicIp>:<port> but no way. is there a solution ?

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
   - http:
       paths:
       - path: /testpath
         pathType: Prefix
         backend:
           service:
           name: market
           port:
             number: 8080
```

Comment: Which Kubernetes distro are you running?

Comment: Can you access the service using the nodePort on the Kubernetes host? Does your host actually have a public ip? Are there any firewall rules (either local on the host, or elsewhere on a network device) that might prevent access to the nodePort?